# Find specific element with html dom

Tags: php

I need to find this element:

```
<p class="bottom_m">Sold out.</p>
```

I tries the following:

```
$html = file_get_html($both[2]);
foreach($html->find('Sold out.') as $element) {
echo $element;
}
```

It is not working and any help is apreciated.

Thanks.

I did the following:

```
include_once ("admin/simple_html_dom.php");

$html = file_get_html($both[2]);

foreach($html->find('p.bottom_m') as $element) { 

$text = trim($element->innertext);

if ($text != "Sold out.") { 


echo "exists";

} // close foreach
} // close if
```

But it shows me the wrong one, because i don't want to see the item that is sold out.

Sietsko

Comment: use `$html->find('p.bottom_m', 0)->plaintext;`

Comment: At the top of your question you say that you want to find the sold out element, at the bottom you say you don't want to find it. Which is it?

Comment: Sorry that was my mistake. I want to seach at the page and when it it not found then continue my code...

Comment: My answer is still valid, just instead of `echo` exit the program or whatever it is you want to do. But if you have another question make a new one, don't keep expanding this one.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
$html->find('p.bottom_m')
```

Here is a full program.

```
require_once 'simple_html_dom.php';

$h = '<html>
        <body>
          <p class="bottom_m">Sold out.</p>
          <p class="bottom_m">NOT SOLD OUT</p>
          <div class="bottom_m"</div>
        </body>
      </html>';

$html = str_get_html($h);

foreach($html->find('p.bottom_m') as $element) {
    $text = trim($element->innertext);
    if ($text === 'Sold out.') {
        echo $text; 
    }
}
```